# Why won't enough current flow through the P-FET?

Tags: mosfet, current, linear-regulator

When I simulate the circuit below, no matter what I set the RDS(on) value of the PFET to, only a few milliamps of current flow through the FET.  More than 90% of the current flows through the regulator.  The FET is fully on (by a very big margin) and even if I add an input resistor to the regulator, very little current flows through the FET.

What have I done wrong?

[image: LinReg]

Comment: If you mark up your schematic with the voltages and currents you're seeing as well as the part numbers or parameters of the components, we could help you more.  What is the overall purpose of the FET?  It looks like it's designed to bypass the regulator if the input voltage gets high enough, but I'm hard pressed to think of a practical application for this.

Comment: You need to provide links to the manufacturer's datasheets for the Zener diode, MOSFET, and voltage regulator, and label your diagram with their part numbers. Why is the MOSFET body unconnected?

Comment: Excuse me, but your rectifier has a shortcut. The substrate of the mosfet is connected to nothing - no hope for proper operation. I must admit I haven't a slightest idea what actually has been thought when one drew this circuit. Maybe you can reveal the design goals.

Comment: @user287001, the goal is to use the FET as a series pass element for the linear regulator.  The zener diode is there to provide the -12V to make sure the FET is switched all the way on from the start.  The circuit actually works in reality, but I'm trying to simulate swapping in different mosfets to try to find the best trade-off between price and performance.

Comment: Works in reality? Then draw it as it is in reality. We can only make guesses, because the drawn circuit never works except if it's intended to be an one shot smoke machine.  Still no idea what's your idea of the achieved benefits of the "series pass element" At least X1 has no way to control the gate of M1.

Comment: If it's suposed to be a series pass, why isn't it in series?

Comment: In a linear regulator circuit, the series-pass element is controlled by the rest of the circuitry. Yours is just sitting in parallel to the "real" regulator, is only very coarsely controlled by the zener, and doesn't account for any of the P-FET's characteristics like Vgs threshold. Could you try to explain in some more detail what exactly you expect the P-FET to do and *why* you expect it to do that?

Comment: use an NPN, not a pmos. and feed the base with the ldo output to tie the rail to ldo-0.6v.

Answer (score 1):

> *What have I done wrong?*

It will never work with your bridge rectifier connected like this: -

[image]

You have the AC terminals connected to the smoothing capacitor and the DC terminals connected to the AC output from the transformer. Other folk have pointed out different problems too.